# Passing scope argument in Controller in Module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm kind of new to AngularJS.

In a text on how to use AngularJS modules I came across the following code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';
```

In this case we are defining a module. Modules as I get are a way to avoid global variables and they define a scope within the rootscope and act as a container for controllers and other objects.

In the myApp.controller(..) line we are passing the $scope object, and also a function object which uses the $scope object. I do not know why it is required to pass the $scope argument. Why is it not possible to just use the $scope variable directly without injecting it into the controller, which I guess is what the first variable in the array is doing.

When a controller is used in an ng-controller tag, then I guess a $scope is automatically created and appended. In that case, isn't it redundant to pass the $scope.

Answer (score 3):

It is not mandatory to pass the $scope argument in the array, you can do as follows:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

//Your code here

});
```

If I'm not getting what you meant, than let me know and I'll explain it to you furthermore !

Answer (score 1):

You're actually not passing the `$scope` object as the first thing, you're declaring that your code *depends on* the `$scope` object to angular's DI system. Omitting it has the same result, but it doesn't work when minified, which is why the array syntax is preferred for minification.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to AngularJS but I am sure I can answer your question partially.

(1): The first variable in the array is assigning a name to the first argument in the function. That is required for minification. See "A Note on Minification": http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

(2): I am not 100% sure, but I would guess the $scope in the function signature is part of AngularJS approach for dependency injection. In this case, it is using a constructor-based dependency injection.

Keep in mind that there are tree kinds of dependency injection: constructor injection, setter injection, interface injection.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [AngularJs documentation for controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), you can use a simpler way to set your controllers in your app. Your example can also be written like :

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';

}
```

More, Angular gives you the possibilty to inject many things as controller arguments in the order you want. So this is also possible to type :

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function (customService1, customService2, $scope) {

    $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';

}
```

And the $scope variable will always be right set.

The "array" way to declare your controller is used to avoid problems occuring when you minify your angular scripts, cause minifiers transform '$scope' in something like 'a' then the Angular parsing will fail.

So, you got two solutions :

- Write your controllers with the 'array' notation if you want to minify your scripts with regular minifiers.

or

- Write your controllers with the 'simple' notation if you don't minify your scripts **OR** if you use [ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) or something like that (I recommend this way).